# How to fix this error in Angular routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {SettingsComponent} from "./settings/settings.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
export const routingComponents = [HomeComponent, SettingsComponent]
```

It works very well but when I add `private  homeservice: HomeService` to the constructor of my `home.component.ts`, my app starts to show me a white page in  the `app.component.html` and I can't do anything. How can I fix this routing problem?

Comment: The question can be improved by showing HomeComponent. Did you register/inject the services by adding `HomeService` in the `providers` of AppModule or HomeComponent?  And provide the info on what error you met.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. 
Ideally someone could drop the code into a online IDE like stackblitz.com 
and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the router-outlet to your app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did not add HomeService in module. You can add it in Provider section of the module. So I think it solves your problem

```
providers: [ HomeService ]
```